# Angular 2 subscribe not executing

Tags: angular

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/arROwxsFYraSBeAZCIYF?p=preview

I'm trying to subscribe to an observer but I can't get it to work. The subscribe method is never activated for some reason, the `notifyAboutChange` runs and the correct id is passed but after calling `next` the subscribe method doesn't seem to pick up on it being called.

The service which contains the observer:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()

export class ApiService {
  public notifier = new Subject();
  public changeOccurrence$ = this.notifier.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  notifyAboutChange(id: string) {
    this.notifier.next(id);
  }
}
```

Directive which calls the `notifyAboutChange` method:

```
constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer, private _api: ApiService) {

  this.eventHandler = _renderer.listen(_elementRef.nativeElement, ('ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchend' : 'click'), (e) => {

    this.isAllChecked = !this.isAllChecked;

    for (let checkbox of this.checkboxes) {

      if (!checkbox.isDisabled) {
        checkbox.isChecked = this.isAllChecked;
      }
    }

    _api.notifyAboutChange(this.componentId);
  });
}
```

Component which should subscribe:

```
export class FormCheckboxMultipleComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
  @Input() model: Array<any>;
  @Input() checkboxes: Array<any>;
  @Output('modelChange') onModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() callback: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private _globals: GlobalVariablesService, private _differs: IterableDiffers, private _api: ApiService) {
    this.ns = _globals.ns;
    this.differ = _differs.find([]).create(null);

    _api.changeOccurrence$.subscribe(
      componentId => {
        console.log(componentId);
        if (this.componentId === componentId) {

          for (let checkbox of this.checkboxes) {

            let existingIndex = this.findIndex(checkbox, this.model);

            if (existingIndex === -1) {
              this.model.push(checkbox);
            }
            else {
              this.model.splice(existingIndex, 1);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    )
  }

  .... excluded parts ....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it could be because you don't share the same instance of the service. You could define the corresponding provider when bootstrapping your application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ ApiService ]);
```

Don't forget to remove the service from the `providers` attribute of components / directives.

Note that you can restrict the scope of the service if necessary. For example by defining it in a component that contains / uses both component and directive.

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/lGgNq5HpqFZCQfGl0Tpw?p=preview.

Comment: Hm no that's not it :/

Comment: You also need to remove the service from `providers` attribute of components / directives...

Comment: Ah my bad, had forgotten to remove it from the directive. OK it kinda makes sense now..